# Magento patch file (diff) can't find file specified

Tags: linux, magento, patch, magento-1.13

I'm executing 1.13.1.0-1.14.0.0.diff, but keep getting `can't find file to patch at input line 5`

tried:

```
~$ patch -p0 -i 1.13.1.0-1.14.0.0.diff
~$ patch -p0 < 1.13.1.0-1.14.0.0.diff
~$ patch < 1.13.1.0-1.14.0.0.diff
~/backup$ patch -p0 -i 1.13.1.0-1.14.0.0.diff
~/backup$ patch -p0 < 1.13.1.0-1.14.0.0.diff
~/backup$ patch < 1.13.1.0-1.14.0.0.diff
```

What am I doing wrong?
Probably can't upload the file cause of licencing but here's how it starts:

```
diff --git a/.githookignore b/.githookignore
index b516512..2182fcd 100644
--- a/.githookignore
+++ b/.githookignore
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Js.php
 dev/tests
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason the file can not be found is because you are specifying 0 leading components to strip from the file names so the patch is looking for file `a/.githookignore` and `b/.githookignore`, which I'm sure do not exist because it has a leading component of a and b respectively.

You simply need to specify the correct number of leading components to strip, which in this case is 1.

Please try the following:
`patch -p1 -i 1.13.1.0-1.14.0.0.diff`

NOTE: The `-i` input option is also required in this case because you are patching from a file instead of stdin.

For additional info please refer to the patch help `patch --help` and/or man page `man patch`.